# The best parameters for my command

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg

Note: I use win10.

My command:
`ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 200M -f gdigrab -thread_queue_size 1024 -probesize 10M -r 10 -draw_mouse 1 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="Stereo mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -c:v libx264 -r 10 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict -2 -ac 2 -b:a 128k -filter_complex "[0]pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[v]; [1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map [v] -map [a] recording.mp4`

Before i will add this command into my app, i have to know, is there way to improve my command.
If u can make my command better(change/add some parameters), write me please. Thank u.

Comment: "better" for what?

Comment: @Tetsujin, My command captures screen. If u can make my command better for its task(capture data from screen), write me please. Thank u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only some minor suggestions:

- Set frame rate at the input level when using a capture device. Otherwise it will try to capture using the default of 25 then drop frames to reach your desired 10 fps. So remove `-r 10` output option and add `-framerate 10` input option for [dshow](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#dshow).
- No need for `-strict -2` for AAC encoding since 2015.
- My personal preference is to use format filter (`format=yuv420p`) instead of `-pix_fmt` if I'm already filtering so it gets applied exactly where I want it to.
- Add `-movflags +faststart` output option to enable fast start playback.
- You set `-video_size 1920x1080`, so you know your output is going to be 1920x1080. Your pad filter is therefore doing nothing as that particular expression is to make sure the output is divisible by 2 (a requirement for libx264 when outputting YUV 4:2:0 chroma subsampling). 1920x1080 is already divisible by 2.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 200M -f gdigrab -thread_queue_size 1024 -probesize 10M -framerate 10 -draw_mouse 1 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="Stereo mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -filter_complex "[0]format=yuv420p[v];[1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map [v] -map [a] -movflags +faststart recording.mp4
```

Comment: ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 200M -f gdigrab -thread_queue_size 1024 -probesize 10M **-framerate 30** -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="Stereo mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p **-movflags +faststart** -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -filter_complex "[0]pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[v]; [1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map [v] -map [a] recording.mp4

Comment: I don't understand what should i don't understand where should i add format=yuv420p.

Comment: @Nikto Example added. Your example in the comment above is missing `-video_size`. Consider adding it unless you're happy with whatever the default will be (and I doubt you still need pad filter). In my example there is no pad and you can use -pix_fmt if you prefer it over format.

Comment: Thank u.But here(You set -video_size 1920x1080, so you know your output is going to be 1920x1080. Your pad filter is therefore doing nothing as that particular expression is to make sure the output is divisible by 2 (a requirement for libx264 when outputting YUV 4:2:0 chroma subsampling). 1920x1080 is already divisible by 2.) u wrote that vide_size in useless, or something like that. Why u didn't delete this option?

Comment: @Nikto `pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2` is useless if your input width and height is divisible by 2 (with no decimals). 1920 is divisible by 2. 1080 is divisible by 2. Therefore your pad is doing nothing.

Comment: What should i do if my input width and height is divisible by 2? add pad?

Comment: @Nikto You don't need pad.

Comment: Thank u for all. But i have the question. Does my command capture data from screen in maximal quality.

Comment: @Nikto Yes, it inputs from screen at max quality.

Comment: if i set -video_size to 1536x864, i get strange behavior, my mouse blinks, but command works and ffmpeg doesn't give me any errors. How to fix it?

Comment: And i have made other tests. Firstly i deleted Microphone input, and after it i had only one input(stereo mix). Then i had deleted this parameters (-filter_complex "[0]format=yuv420p[v];[1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map [v] -map [a]) and i ran my command, and my cursor also blinked.

Comment: @Nikto The blinking issue should be asked as a new question.

Comment: that's my new question.https://superuser.com/questions/1589525/cursor-blinks-ffmpeg