# Cursor blinks ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 200M -f gdigrab -thread_queue_size 1024 -probesize 10M -framerate 30 -draw_mouse 1 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="Stereo mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -filter_complex "[0]format=yuv420p[v];[1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map [v] -map [a] -movflags +faststart recording.mp4
```

That's my command. It works fine, but have made some tests:

1. I deleted Microphone input from my command and now i have only Stereo Mix input. And also i deleted this(-filter_complex "[0]format=yuv420p[v];[1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map [v] -map [a]) from my command. And when i run my new command my cursor blinks, however i don't get any errors from ffmpeg. My command works like early, but now cursor blinks. [Log for 1)](https://pastebin.com/K0ihJ9jf)
2. i just changed -video_size to 1536x864. And i have the same result(And when i run my new command my cursor blinks, however i don't get any errors from ffmpeg. My command works like early, but now cursor blinks.)

**UPD:**
"Bug" for 2) gone.
I don't why, but my command for 2) (`ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 200M -f gdigrab -thread_queue_size 1024 -probesize 10M -framerate 30 -draw_mouse 1 -video_size 1536x864 -i desktop -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="Stereo mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -filter_complex "[0]format=yuv420p[v];[1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map [v] -map [a] -movflags +faststart recording.mp4`) works normal, without any blinkings!

How can i fix it?
Thank u

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the complete console output from the ffmpeg command. Please copy and paste the text instead of making an image of the text.

Comment: @llogan, i have edited my question

Comment: This happens to me when screen recording with ffmpeg too. I think it's because the program is capturing those frames. It doesn't affect the output file (at least it doesn't for me)

Comment: @llogan,. Do u know, is there any solution?

Comment: @Nikto So it blinks at 1920x1080 but not at 1536x864? I don't use Windows so I may not be of much help.

Comment: @llogan, no, i don't know why, but my bag 2) gone. For now have only bug 1) (
I deleted Microphone input from my command and now i have only Stereo Mix input. And also i deleted this(-filter_complex "[0]format=yuv420p[v];[1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map [v] -map [a]) from my command. And when i run my new command my cursor blinks, however i don't get any errors from ffmpeg. My command works like early, but now cursor blinks
)
Pls, see this(https://pastebin.com/K0ihJ9jf). That link is  ffmpeg's log. In that link you also will be able to find command that i used

Comment: @Nikto Does the cursor look better if you change `-framerate 10` to `-framerate 30`?
If not I recommend testing dshow ([documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#dshow), [wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop#Windows)) and seeing if that looks better than gdigrab.

Comment: @llogan, i already use -framerate 30 instead of -framerate 10

Comment: @Nikto Your command in the question showed `-framerate 10`. You should always show the actual command you are using so you don't get bogus suggestions.

Comment: @llogan, sorry, for now i have edited qut

Comment: @llogan, i have another question. How can i check if -vedeo_size parammeter is valid or not?

Comment: @Nikto Don't use a size bigger than your screen. Don't use odd numbered values unless you add scale, crop, or pad. Did you ever test to see if dshow works?

Comment: @llogan, bug completely gone, i don't know what's going on:))
That's my command bellow for one input:
ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 200M -f gdigrab -thread_queue_size 1024 -probesize 10M -framerate 30 -draw_mouse 1 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k **-pix_fmt yuv420p** -movflags +faststart recording.mp4

Should i use this -pix_fmt yuv420p parameter in my command?

Comment: @llogan, i was wrong, bug hasn't completely gone. bug exists for commands like that(ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 200M -f gdigrab -thread_queue_size 1024 -probesize 10M -framerate 30 -draw_mouse 1 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -movflags +faststart recording.mp4 ) without  audio inputs

Comment: @llogan, do u know how can i fix that?

Comment: @Nikto Yes, you need `-pix_fmt yuv420p` or else it won't play on some players. *"do u know how can i fix that?"* Again, you can try [dshow](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop#Windows) instead of gdigrab and see if it looks better.

Comment: @llogan, ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast output.mkv that's my new command. That's works without any blinkings. I gonna close issue. At last i wanna ask witch parameters should i add to my command to improve it?

Comment: @Nikto Suggestions to improve it depends on the use case. Is the output for uploading to YouTube? For a video editor? Just local playback? For viewing on a phone? Etc.

Comment: @llogan, i wrote that simple command:
ffmpeg -y -f gdigrab -i desktop -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p recording_test.mp4
My command doesn't work.
I don't see valid screen translation in my recording.mp4 output file.
But command bellow works good
ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 200M -f gdigrab -thread_queue_size 1024 -probesize 10M -framerate 30 -draw_mouse 1 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="My micro" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart recording.mp4

Comment: @llogan, i have found solution for my all issues, but i have one question. If i replace recording.mp4 to any video extension(for ex .ts, .mov...), will my command work?

Comment: @llogan, have u seen that(https://superuser.com/questions/1594001/ffmpeg-capture-window-bug?noredirect=1#comment2429068_1594001) in this question i described a really big problem, help me. That isn't dumb question