# ffmpeg capture window bug

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

`ffmpeg-f gdigrab -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -draw_mouse 1 -i title=Calculator -c:v libx264  -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast recording.mp4`
That's my command. When i run it i get this error:

```
[gdigrab @ 000001632c6ee400] Capture area (0,0),(1920,1080) extends outside window area (0,0),(718,671)title=Calculator: I/O error
```

How can i fix that?
Thank u

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115179/discussion-on-question-by-nikto-ffmpeg-capture-window-bug).